# Terminal does not recognize git

Tags: git

None of my git repositories work. I open the terminal and I go to the folder where I have git: cd ... I usually see a green asterisk . It means that it recognizes that the folder has git. But now, I do not see the green asterisk. It happens with all my repositories.

I have checked that inside the folder there is the .git hidden folder.

I have updated my Operating Sistem. Now I have MacOS Sierra 10.12 I do not know if there is any relation. It has a coincidence in time.

I tried to create a new repository in a test folder:
cd test
git init

Then, the terminal say: 
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

I am new, I do not understand what does it mean. Can anyone explain, please

Comment: Check the contents of /usr/local for anything you might have installed. OSX updates have been cleaning that hierarchy out recently.

Comment: does git command line actually work? have you tried?

Comment: Assuming that the asterisk is part of your prompt (the characters shown before each of your commands) you could check your prompt configuration if it contains anything that prints the asterisk: `echo $PS1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of things I could find that the program XCode creates some problem. I had a new version of XCode downloaded but not opened yet. When I opened and agreed to the new conditions, git and the terminal work well again.